# how to use substring in Ionic 2

Tags: html, string, split, ionic2, substring

I'm trying to view the first n letters of dinamic string in ionic 2 by using substring but I coudn't find the solution for my problem.

for example: I have firebase list that contain fname, lname, and uid. I want to print the first 5 or 6 letters of 'uid' and I use this way to split it but my application show me an error

**part of my html code:**

```
<p><b>{{list.fname}}_{{list.uid.substring(1,6)}}</b></p>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Toto it show me " cannot read property 'substring' of undefined "

Comment: I don't know well ionic but it seems that `list.uid` is not defined. What happens when you print it?

Comment: @Toto there is no errors if I removed substring, I think there is some thing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I forgot '?'

```
<p><b>{{chat.fname}}_{{(chat.uid)?.substring(1,6)}}
```

Comment: You could also do this: `<p><b>{{ chat.fname + '_' +
 chat.uid?.substring(1,6) }}</b></p>`